# My requestcall from VueJS Frontend to C# API wont show anything in body

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, httprequest

I am Working at a VueJS Webapplication with a c# WebAPI in the background. I made already one endpoint but I cant get it to work. The body of the response is always null. When i check the debug section on the network tab, i can see the message i want to get in the preview section, but I cant get it to show on the page.

VueJS component:

```
<template>
    <div class="dashboard">
        <button type="button" id="get-joke" @click="fetchAPIData">Get a Joke!!</button>
        <div v-if="responseAvailable == true">
            <hr>
            <p>
                <i>{{result}}</i>
            </p>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        props: {
            msg: String
        },
        components: {
        },
        Data() {
            result: null,
            responseAvailable: null
        },
        
        methods: {
            fetchAPIData() {
                this.responseAvailable = false;
                fetch("https://localhost:44322/api/values", {
                    "mode": "no-cors",
                    "method": "GET",
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        alert(response); //checking if i get something
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.result = response.body;
                        this.responseAvailable = true;
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        var error = err;
                        return error;
                    });
            }
        }

    };
</script>
```

C# API Controller (returning a JSON string of a list of Objects) :

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MO_Backend.Services;
using MO_Backend.APIServices;

namespace MO_Backend.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly O_UserService _oUserService;
        public ValuesController(O_UserService oUserService)
        {
            _oUserService = oUserService;
        }

        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public String Get()
        {
            OnlineCheckService occ = new OnlineCheckService(_oUserService);
            return occ.GetRobotState();
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong or an alternative to what im trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the no-cors mode in your http request. This results in an opaque request, which means you get a response, but you cannot use the data. You need to use cors and set the response headers in your backend accordingly.